# Transfer game license

Tags: ps4

So the problem is that account 1 and account 2 bought a game together, but account 1 isn't used anymore. Can we transfer the game license from account 1 to account 3?

The game was bought on account 1 and account 2 activated account 1 as primary.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot transfer games / licenses between accounts. Sony / PlayStation does not offer such functionality for digital games, so you'll need to keep Account 1 around to play any games purchased on that account.